# using numpy to get rid of a loop

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am looking for a way to replace a double loop into a matrix operation using numpy. I have a list of coordinates reprensenting the four nodes of a square.
Such as [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)]. From that square I want to make a grid of 10 by 10 squares.

I dont know how to use numpy to achieve that.So i used loops instead.

## using shapely to transform sequence of coordinates into an object for #geopandas

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import numpy as np

# coordinate defining the size of the grid
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = [0, 0, 10, 10]

# defining the size of the basic square of the grid
height = 10
width = 10

# counting  number of squares the function has to make to create the grid
rows = int(np.ceil((ymax - ymin) / height))
cols = int(np.ceil((xmax - xmin) / width))

# coordinates of the first square
XleftOrigin = xmin
XrightOrigin = xmin + width
YtopOrigin = ymax
YbottomOrigin = ymax - height

# making to list to keep track of the squares and id of the square
polygons = []
p_id = []
cpt = 0

# looping over cols and rows to generate every square of the grid by #translating the coordinate of the first square
for i in range(0,cols):
    Ytop = YtopOrigin
    Ybottom = YbottomOrigin
    for j in range(0,rows):
        polygons.append(Polygon([(XleftOrigin, Ytop), (XrightOrigin, Ytop), (XrightOrigin, Ybottom), (XleftOrigin, Ybottom)]))
        p_id.append(str(cpt))
        cpt += 1
        Ytop = Ytop - height
        Ybottom = Ybottom - height

    XleftOrigin = XleftOrigin + width
    XrightOrigin = XrightOrigin + width
```

I would like to use numpy to replace this double loops but i dont know where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could take a look at the numpy meshgrid functionality. I'm not sure what your final result should look like but in the following manner you easily find all the coordinates of the x and y points:

```
import numpy as np


xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = [0., 0., 200., 200.]

# defining the size of the basic square of the grid
height = 10
width = 10

# counting  number of squares the function has to make to create the grid
rows = int(np.ceil((ymax - ymin) / height))
cols = int(np.ceil((xmax - xmin) / width))

# linspace gives a vector of a number of pieces between min and max
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, cols+1)
y = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, rows+1) # the +1 because of an "added border" instead of counting the squares, the corners are one point more

x_mat, y_mat = np.meshgrid(x, y) # here are 2 lists of lists corresponding to the lengths of x and y given.
```